# Wordpress Pulling in multiple posts that share the same category

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to pull in thumbnails from posts that come from category id "Theme 01" aka id 117 and from category called "ingredients" aka id 46. So far I got it to work but I want to also pull in posts that match "Theme 01" and "recipes". Also posts that match "Theme 01" and "chef" etc. You get the idea. I tried adding another category id to the array but no luck.

```
 <?php 
   $my_query_args = array('posts_per_page' => 6,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => array( 117, 46, 65 ),
            'operator' => 'AND'
        )
    )
);

$my_query = new WP_Query( $my_query_args );

if( $my_query->have_posts() ) : while( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

<li>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array(46,65)); ?></a>
</li>


<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```